# Line Drawing in ncurses

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, ncurses, extended-ascii

I've been trying to do simple line drawing (e.g. boxes) in ncurses all day, but I can't get it to work. I'm trying to print extended ASCII characters like the ones found here: http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-table-codes/ascii-codes-219.html
I've seen a few mentions to wchar_t, but it apparently requires ncursesw, which I can't figure out how to include (I know it's installed)

I'm using XCode under OS X 10.6.2 and GCC 4.2.

Any ideas?

Comment: What programming environment is this in?  I assumed C/C++ in my answer below.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need wchar_t.  The "extended" codes (c. 1985) are less than 255.  For example, to draw the left lower corner of a double-lined box, use code 200 decimal, 310 octal ("\310") or 0xc8 ("\xc8").

Those characters need support from the terminal emulator you are using, but it should work fine.

---

**edit**
I have a vague memory of a 7-bit vs. 8-bit mode for old curses, but I cannot find any mention of it in the FSF ncurses 1.190 (2008/12/20), also identified as v5.7.3.20090207 which I have on Linux.  The [man page for curs_addch](http://www.unix.com/man-page/FreeBSD/3/mvwaddch/) mentions symbolic constants for line drawing characters, so perhaps you are expected to use those instead of literal line drawing characters:

```
addch (ACS_ULCORNER);   // upper left corner
for (int j = 0;  j < boxwidth-2;  ++j)
    addch (ACS_HLINE);
addch (ACS_URCORNER);   // upper right
...
```

Comment: When I try this, ncurses just draws question marks. (I'm using C, by the way. Plain ol' C)

Comment: And yes, I checked my terminal; I can paste extended ascii into it fine.

Comment: Well, this gets me a bit closer; the line drawing constants show up as Qs, consistent with this issue: http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#no_line_drawing . It seems to be due to terminal incompatibility, but I've tried in it Terminal.app as well as xterm, and neither work.

Comment: What is the value of environment variable `TERM`?  On my system it is `xterm`.

Comment: I've got `xterm-color|nxterm|generic color xterm` for Terminal.app.

Comment: Do you mean that the `TERM` variable has that whole string in it?  I don't recall that as being useful, but maybe terminfo has a method of dealing with that.  Is one of those in the terminfo database?

Comment: That's included in the output of `infocmp`; I'm not sure if that's the correct way of finding it.

Answer (score 1):

```
void boxAround( int y, int x, int h, int w ) {
    move( y, x );
    addch (ACS_ULCORNER);   // upper left corner
    int j;
    for (j = 0;  j < w;  ++j)
        addch (ACS_HLINE);
    addch (ACS_URCORNER);   // upper right

    for( j = 0; j < h; ++j ) {
            move(  y+1+j, x );
            addch (ACS_VLINE);
            move( y+1+j, x+w+1 );
            addch (ACS_VLINE);
    }

    move( y+h+1,x );
    addch (ACS_LLCORNER);   // lower left corner

    for (j = 0;  j < w;  ++j)
        addch (ACS_HLINE);
    addch (ACS_LRCORNER);   // lower right
}
```